# Local GitLab software for Mac

Tags: git, macos, gitlab

I recently buy a Mac.
In my windows I use TortoiseGit to connect to local GitLab with a .ppk key.

But in Mac I cant find any software for commit/pull/push and connect to my GitLab with the IP address of it.

Did you guys know any software for do the same as TortoiseGit?
Software like GitKraken cant link to a local GitLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't GitKraken be able to connect to a local repository? Anyway, the Git home page has a list of macOS GUI clients you may want to give a try:

https://git-scm.com/download/gui/mac

Also I think Xcode has integrated Git support.

Comment: Hm i dont find the option for link the IP in gitKraken. But that's a good idea to commit pull push with the software !

Comment: https://support.gitkraken.com/getting-started/guide <- There are instructions for "Cloning an existing project". "Clone with URL" should also take IP addresses,